# ifstream read reading random char for the whole stream

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement the function from listing 5.1 [here](https://github.com/jagregory/abrash-black-book/blob/master/src/chapter-05.md)
but when copying into a buffer with read from a file I just get the same character (Í) for the whole array, where string.txt is a copy and paste from the previous link content. [image]
 Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

const int block_size = 0x4000;   //16KB

int search(char* buffer, int searchLength, char* stringToSearch, int stringToSearchLength) {
    char * potentialMatch;
    while (searchLength) {
        potentialMatch = reinterpret_cast<char *>(memchr(buffer, *stringToSearch, searchLength));
        if (potentialMatch == NULL)
            break;

        if (stringToSearchLength == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (!memcmp(potentialMatch + 1, stringToSearch + 1, stringToSearchLength - 1))
                return 1;
        }

        searchLength -= potentialMatch - buffer + 1;
        buffer = potentialMatch + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *toSearch = "Interpreting Where";
    int done = 0;
    int found = 0;  
    char *buffer;
    int64_t fileSizeLeft = 0;

    std::ifstream myFile("string.txt");
    if (!myFile.fail()) {
        buffer = new char[block_size];   
        myFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);   //Get file's size
        fileSizeLeft = myFile.tellg();    
    } else {
        std::cout << "Cannot open file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int toSearchLength = strlen(toSearch);
    int stringLeft = toSearchLength - 1;
    int first_time = 1;


    while (!done && fileSizeLeft > toSearchLength) {
        if (first_time) {
            myFile.read(buffer, block_size);
            found = search(buffer, block_size, toSearch, toSearchLength);
        } else {
            memcpy(buffer, buffer + stringLeft, stringLeft);
            myFile.read(buffer+stringLeft, fileSizeLeft-stringLeft);        
            found = search(buffer, block_size, toSearch, toSearchLength);
        }

        fileSizeLeft = fileSizeLeft - block_size;
        first_time = 0;
    }


    if (found) {
        std::cout << "String found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "String not found" << std::endl;
    }

    myFile.close();
    delete[] buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can help me see what I'm doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: I don't see the part of returning the file internal position to the beginning, you see what is the size of the file and leave the position at the end.  You seem to be reading garbage.

Comment: Í is the textual interpretation of the binary value 0xcd which is the value that Visual Studio's debug mode puts in uninitialized memory.

Comment: Just remove the here in the link, try [this](https://github.com/jagregory/abrash-black-book/blob/master/src/chapter-05.md)

Comment: @EdMaster Thanks that was it! Post it as an answer so I can accept it :)!

Comment: Hello @Aram:  usually, for very small issues it is not good etiquette to put an answer but a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `myFile`'s position to `ios_base::end` with [`seekg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/):

```
myFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
```

Then trying to read from it:

```
myFile.read(buffer, block_size);
```

Clearly no data will be read since `myFile` is already at `ios_base::end`. And you'll be reading whatever uninitialized data that was already in `buffer`

What you probably intended to do was to set your `myFile` position back to the beginning by doing this before reading:

```
myFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```